# D3.js Chart Transition Erroring

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, brush

I'm trying to brush #histogram1 and redraw a sub-chart #histogram2.

The redrawing is not working properly, around line 113 in my example.

The console is occasionally showing errors on the "height" and "y" attributes -

```
Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I am unable to determine where the bad values are coming from?

Can some help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```js
var data = [
{"yr":1940,"type":"E","rate":40},{"yr":1947,"type":"A","rate":20},{"yr":1943,"type":"B","rate":30},{"yr":1950,"type":"B","rate":25}, 
{"yr":1943,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1941,"type":"A","rate":30},{"yr":1945,"type":"E","rate":40},{"yr":1948,"type":"A","rate":20},
{"yr":1947,"type":"B","rate":30},{"yr":1950,"type":"B","rate":25},{"yr":1945,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1941,"type":"A","rate":30}, 
{"yr":1944,"type":"B","rate":10},{"yr":1949,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1940,"type":"E","rate":10},{"yr":1940,"type":"E","rate":40},
{"yr":1940,"type":"E","rate":40},{"yr":1947,"type":"A","rate":20},{"yr":1943,"type":"B","rate":30},{"yr":1950,"type":"B","rate":25}, 
{"yr":1943,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1941,"type":"A","rate":30},{"yr":1945,"type":"E","rate":40},{"yr":1948,"type":"A","rate":20},
{"yr":1947,"type":"B","rate":30},{"yr":1950,"type":"D","rate":25},{"yr":1945,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1941,"type":"A","rate":30}, 
{"yr":1944,"type":"B","rate":10},{"yr":1949,"type":"C","rate":20},{"yr":1940,"type":"E","rate":10},{"yr":1947,"type":"E","rate":40}
];

// CROSSFILTER Dimensions //
var cfdata = crossfilter(data)
  , all = cfdata.groupAll()
  , year = cfdata.dimension(function(d) {return d.yr;})
  , type = cfdata.dimension(function(d) {return d.type;})
  , years= year.group()
  , types= type.group().reduceCount()
  , typeKeys = types.all()
  , keyMap = typeKeys.map (function(d) {return d.key}) ;

// General CHART Dimensions //
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10, left: 10}
  , height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom
  , width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right
  , barPadding = 5 ;

// Setup TOOLTIPS //
var tip = d3.tip()
       .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
       .html(function(d){return d.value});
    
// HISTOGRAM 1 : TOTAL BY YEAR //
var min1 = d3.min(years.all(), function(d) {return d.key;})
  , max1 = d3.max(years.all(), function(d) {return d.key;})
  , range1 = max1 - min1 ;
  
var xScale1 = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([min1, max1])
        .range([0, width]) ;   

var yScale1 = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(years.all(), function(d) {return d.value;})])
        .range([height / 2, 0]) ;

var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale1)
        .ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
         .orient("bottom") ;

var histogram1 = d3.select("#histogram1").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g");

    histogram1.call(tip);

    histogram1.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(xAxis1)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height / 2 + ")") ;

    histogram1.selectAll("rect")
        .data(years.all())
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale1(d.key) + 0.5 * (width / range1)})
        .attr("width", width / range1)
        .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale1(d.value);})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return (height / 2 - yScale1(d.value));})
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide); 

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(xScale1)
        .extent([1945, 1946])
        .on("brush", brushmove) ;

var brushg = histogram1.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush) ;

    brushg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("height", height / 2) ;

    brushg.selectAll(".resize")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", resizePath) ;

function brushmove() {
    var s = brush.extent()
      , lower = parseInt(s[0])
      , upper = parseInt(s[1]);
    
    histogram1.selectAll("rect")
        .style("opacity", function(d) {return lower <= d.key && d.key <= upper ? "1" : ".2";}) ;

    var filt = year.filterRange([lower,upper]);
    
    console.log(filt.top(Infinity));

    histogram2.selectAll("rect")
        .data(filt.top(Infinity))
        .transition()
        .attr("y", function(d){ return height - yScale2(d); })
        .attr("height", function(d){ return yScale2(d); })
};

// HISTOIGRAM 2 : TOTAL BY TYPE //
var keys2 = typeKeys.map(function(d) {return d.key;})
  , min2 = d3.min(types, function(d) {return d.key;})
  , max2 = d3.max(types, function(d) {return d.key;})
  
var xScale2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
         .domain(keys2)
         .rangeBands([0, width]);   

var yScale2 = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(types.all(), function(d) {return d.value;})])
         .range([height / 2, 0]);

var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(xScale2)
         .orient("bottom");

var histogram2 = d3.select("#histogram2").append("svg:svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g");  

     histogram2.call(tip);
 
     histogram2.append("g")
         .attr("class", "axis")
         .call(xAxis2)
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .selectAll("text")
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("dx", "-.8em")
         .attr("dy", ".15em")
         .attr("transform", function(d) {return "rotate(-65)"});

   histogram2.selectAll("rect")
         .data(types.all())
         .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale2(d.key);})
         .attr("width", width / keyMap.length - barPadding)
         .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale2(d.value); })
         .attr("height", function(d) {return height - yScale2(d.value);})
         .attr("fill", "steelblue")
         .on("mouseover", tip.show)
         .on("mouseout", tip.hide);   



function resizePath(d) {
    var e = +(d == "e")
      , x = e ? 1 : -1
      , y = height / 4;
    return "M" + (.5 * x) + "," + y + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (6.5 * x) + "," + (y + 6) + "V" + (2 * y - 6) + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (.5 * x) + "," + (2 * y) + "Z" + "M" + (2.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8) + "M" + (4.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8);
}
```

```css
/*** d3-tip styles */
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.d3-tip.n:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: -1px 0 0;
}
/*** D3 brush */
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #222;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<div id="histogram1"></div>
<div id="histogram2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different data when updating the second histogram in response to the brush, from when you initially drew the chart. Generally you'll want to use the same group's data (`.all()`) in both cases.

In particular,

```
.data(filt.top(Infinity))
```

will supply the raw rows of your data to the chart, and

```
.attr("y", function(d){ return height - yScale2(d); })
.attr("height", function(d){ return yScale2(d); })
```

will then attempt to pass those row objects to the scale, when the scale is expecting a number. (An object is literally "Not a Number".)

When you apply the filter

```
year.filterRange([lower,upper]);
```

that will cause all of the groups in associated crossfilter to re-filter and re-aggregate. (It's very much an imperative, not functional programming, interface. The `filter` method just returns the same dimension object.)

If you update `y` and `height` exactly as you drew it in the first place:

```
.attr("y", function(d){ return height - yScale2(d.value); })
.attr("height", function(d){ return yScale2(d.value); })
```

then presto! it filters.

[image: wonderful cross filtering]

Fiddle with corrected code: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/hjL6rf9u/5/